# Gulp Git run first commit task then push task

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-git

I am working on project and I want to commit and push on git using by gulp but I am facing some issue when I am running git task so push then task is not waiting for commit....

Anyone can do my help! I want to make the task like first run commit and then push automatically and don't run push task until complete commit task....

Gulp Task for Gulp Git Commit and Push!

```js
var gulp              = require('gulp'),
    runSequence       = require('run-sequence'),
    gutil             = require('gulp-util'),
    git               = require('gulp-git'),
    prompt            = require('gulp-prompt');


/* task to commit and push all file on git
******************************************************************/
// git commit task with gulp prompt
gulp.task('gulp:commit', function(){
  // just source anything here - we just wan't to call the prompt for now
  gulp.src('./*')
  .pipe(prompt.prompt({
    type: 'input',
    name: 'commit',
    message: 'Please enter commit message...'
  }, function(res){
    // now add all files that should be committed
    // but make sure to exclude the .gitignored ones, since gulp-git tries to commit them, too
    return gulp.src([ '!node_modules/', './*' ], {buffer:false})
    .pipe(git.commit(res.commit));
   }));
});

// Run git push, remote is the remote repo, branch is the remote branch to push to
gulp.task('gulp:push', ['gulp:commit'], function(cb){
    git.push('origin', 'master', cb, function(err){
        if (err) throw err;
    });
});

// # task completed notification with green color!
gulp.task('gulp:done', ['gulp:push'], function(){
  console.log('');
  gutil.log(gutil.colors.green('************** Git push is done! **************'));
  console.log('');
});

// gulp task to commit and push data on git
gulp.task('git', function(){
  runSequence(['gulp:commit', 'gulp:push', 'gulp:done'])
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're telling *runSequence* plugin to run the tasks in parallel. The solution is really simple:

```
// gulp task to commit and push data on git
gulp.task('git', function(){
  return runSequence('gulp:commit', 'gulp:push', 'gulp:done');
});
```

By doing this you ensure that **gulp:push** will run only after **gulp:commit** finished, and after the push is done **gulp:done** will run.

Also, I recommend you return the stream in **gulp:push** and use the done callback parameter in **gulp:done**, if you don't do that gulp doesn't know when this tasks ends:

```
// git commit task with gulp prompt
gulp.task('gulp:commit', function(){
  // just source anything here - we just wan't to call the prompt for now
  return gulp.src('./*')
  .pipe(prompt.prompt({
    type: 'input',
    name: 'commit',
    message: 'Please enter commit message...'
  }, function(res){
    // now add all files that should be committed
    // but make sure to exclude the .gitignored ones, since gulp-git tries to commit them, too
    return gulp.src([ '!node_modules/', './*' ], {buffer:false})
    .pipe(git.commit(res.commit));
   }));
});

// Run git push, remote is the remote repo, branch is the remote branch to push to
gulp.task('gulp:push', ['gulp:commit'], function(cb){
  return git.push('origin', 'master', cb, function(err){
    if (err) throw err;
  });
});

// # task completed notification with green color!
gulp.task('gulp:done', ['gulp:push'], function(done){
  console.log('');
  gutil.log(gutil.colors.green('************** Git push is done! **************'));
  console.log('');
  done();
});
```

EDIT: You have to return the stream in **gulp:commit** task too, I changed my answer to show you how.

Comment: not working... and push task is not waiting for completed for commit task!

Comment: You don't return the stream in **gulp:commit** too. I editted my answer to show you how, try that and tell me if it works.

Comment: thanks, this code is working but i noticed one thing that it is not pushing my current commit but pushing recent commit on gitihub!

Comment: I think I cannot help you with that problem, I don't use **gulp-git** plugin myself.
I am glad to see my answer help you, please give me an upvote if it was useful to you :D

Answer (score 0):

gulp-git commit doesn't actually return a stream (by design). See [Commit doesn't fire `end` #49](https://github.com/stevelacy/gulp-git/issues/49).

To get around this, you can use a promise library like [bluebird](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/getting-started.html).

**Here's what worked for me, as suggested by github user bfricka :**

```
gulp.task('commit-changes', function (cb) {


    var q = require('bluebird'); //commit needs a a promise
    return new q(function (resolve, reject) {



        gulp.src('../')
                .pipe(git.add())
                .pipe(stream = git.commit("my commit message")).on('error', function (e) {
            console.log('No changes to commit');
        })

                .on('error', resolve) //resolve to allow the commit to resume even when there are not changes.
                .on('end', resolve);



        stream.resume(); //needed since commmit doesnt return stream by design.


        ;


    });

});
```